# Loading View Controller's Outlet view Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to see if this would be a good option? I am trying to generalize info button -> to one view controller with different views

My model looks like:

1. ViewController

   1. View One
   2. View Two
   3. View Three

Now I am trying to set all these view in Case bases, based on where the info button is going to click on different view controller, that particular view is going to show with respect to the info view controller. In order to achieve this, I had an idea of connecting simply the outlet for the view controller on the run-time to the view I want to set.

Is there anyway to set the Outlet pro-grammatically at run-time?

Thanks

Comment: Well, not sure that I understand your question correctly, but what about programmaticaly creating views? If you need for those views just create with `alloc`-`init` methods. For button you can set actions.

Comment: beryllium, the only concern here is that I have many view controller's which have info button, therefore doing that so will just take more time. this way I just have to create a case method and assign the view on the fly. I am just trying to understand how an "file owner's" outlet which get connected to the view can be done programmatically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can set any property at runtime.

Longer answer: Yes, You can set any property (e.g. `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView`) at runtime. An outlet is simply a property that is defined with `IBOutlet` to allow interface builder to see it as an available outlet. If you are only going to assign the property at runtime you don't need to define the property as IBOutlet. Not sure how you've architected your app so don't know if you want to conditionally create a view controller or a view. In any case, at runtime, you set the property as you would any other property based on the condition you are checking.

Comment: XJones, I am neither creating conditionally the viewcontroller or the views, all I am doing is setting the view based on which controller it tends to be at. So lets say you have an info button in 20 different view controller's, so realistically I don't want to create 20 different view controllers to have some information about whats there, but what I thought would be easier is to create one generic view controller with multiple views based on which controller it resides in, and set itself as an outlet. Hope it makes some sense? I could do as beryllium mentioned but it will safe some time.

Comment: not sure I understand what you are trying to do. in iOS you generally create objects as needed. It's reasonable to have a single view controller that displays different info based on context so you could have a bunch of views defined and when you set a property in that view controller have it create and display the appropriate view and remove/release any views no longer needed. All of this of course, at runtime.

Comment: XJones, I guess adding and removing view's is the only way, I was thinking maybe connecting to file's owner outlet initially would do the trick, as those view in interface builder are the objects as well right? so if you know which view you need to connect to the file owner, then no need to keep on removing/releasing and then adding.. just trying to safe some iterative process here..

Comment: you can implement it that way. e.g. you can create 20 views in your NIB file and give them tags. When you want to set the outlet, look up the view with a specific tag, assign it to the outlet and add it to the superview. when setting the outlet you would also remove the old view from the superview.

Comment: just to clarify something, how to set the outlet with respect to tag? Is it something that can be done programmatically? adding and removing portion I got it, but just trying to figure out how would I assign it to outlet, as per with tags. Thanks for giving the update on tags as well, that's something I didn't had thought about.

Comment: Assuming all your views are subviews of the main view in your NIB file and they are hidden until needed do the following: `newView = [self.view viewWithTag:viewTag]`. The you have the view and can work with it including setting it to a specific outlet (property). I don't recommend this approach though. A better approach would be to define all the views in a different NIB and load that when needed and then access the desired view. Look into the docs as to how to load/access views in NIB files.

Comment: I guess the un-desired approach tends to become more of a weak binding. I will definitely look into the docs. Thanks